# Using Synergy between two clients with different resolutions

Tags: linux, fedora, synergy

I have two fedora systems (running synergy 1.3.7) each with two displays.  The synergy server has two displays arranged horizontally and the client has two displays arranged vertically.

[image: monitor layout]

When I go from the server to the client the mouse goes from DVI-I-2 -> HDMI2.  I have used xrandr to define VGA1 as the primary of the system but it does not seem to honor it.  Additionally, when I try to mouse down from HDMI2 -> VGA1 the cursor seems to stop just past the "seam" between the two displays.

My end goal is to be able to mouse from DVI-I-2 -> VGA1 and from VGA1 -> HDMI2 and then from HDMI-2 or VGA-1 back to DVI-I-2.

*NOTE: The "native" mouse works correctly between VGA1 and HDMI2.  It only sticks at the "seam" when using the mouse from the synergy server*

To configure the client I used the following xrandr command

`xrandr --output VGA1 --auto --primary --output HDMI2 --auto --above VGA1`

My current synergy.conf

```
section: screens
    tinnytim:
    calculon:
end

section: links
    tinnytim:
        right = calculon
    calculon:
        left = tinnytim
end
```

Comment: I have tried with the most recent build of synergy (1.4.8) and it still fails the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue came with the fact that I needed to restart the synergy client *after* running the xrandr command.  I'm assuming that synergy still thinks that the screen resolution is the old size.